# External CSS in Shiny Dashboard

Tags: css, shiny, shinydashboard

I'm trying to modify Shiny dashboard apperance by using CSS.

I've first used internal CSS as below and it works as expected.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

# Internal CSS - works fine


ui <- shinydashboard::dashboardPage(
  shinydashboard::dashboardHeader(title = "MyDashboard"),
  
  shinydashboard::dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Main", tabName = "Main", icon = icon("home"), startExpanded = TRUE,
               menuSubItem("Tab1", tabName = "Tab1", icon = icon("chart-line")),
               menuSubItem("Tab2", tabName = "Tab2", icon = icon("chart-line")),
               menuSubItem("Tab3", tabName = "Tab3", icon = icon("dashboard"))
      )
    )
  ),
  
  shinydashboard::dashboardBody(
    tags$head(tags$style(HTML('
      
        .skin-blue .main-header .logo {
                              background-color: #193807;
                              }

 
        
        .skin-blue .main-header .navbar {
                              background-color: #193807;
                              }
       
        .skin-blue .main-sidebar {
                              background-color: #193807;
                              }  
                              '
                              ))),
    fluidPage(
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output) { }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Now I want to do the same by refering to an external CSS file. So I create a mystyle.css file inside www directory, which is located insise the folder, in which I have the file with dashboard app (so, if the app is in C:\Documents\Myapp, then the css file is in C:\Documents\Myapp\www).

The css file looks as follows:

```
.skin-blue .main-header .logo {
    background-color: #193807;
}

.skin-blue .main-header .navbar {
    background-color: #193807;
}

.skin-blue .main-sidebar {
    background-color: #193807;
}
```

I refer to the css file with a tags$head and tags$link as shown below. But it's not working. What's wrong?

```
# External CSS - not working

ui <- shinydashboard::dashboardPage(
  shinydashboard::dashboardHeader(title = "MyDashboard"),
  
  shinydashboard::dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Main", tabName = "Main", icon = icon("home"), startExpanded = TRUE,
               menuSubItem("Tab1", tabName = "Tab1", icon = icon("chart-line")),
               menuSubItem("Tab2", tabName = "Tab2", icon = icon("chart-line")),
               menuSubItem("Tab3", tabName = "Tab3", icon = icon("dashboard"))
      )
    )
  ),
  
  shinydashboard::dashboardBody(
    tags$head(tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type="text/css", href="mystyle.css")),
    fluidPage(
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output) { }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a very late reply to your question, however I feel I must answer as I too struggled linking my external CSS to my Shiny dashboard.

The method that worked for me was to use the function `includeCSS("www/style.css")` which I read about in this [Shiny post](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/css.html).

Below is an example of how I used this function in my Shiny app.R UI. Note that the `includeCSS()` function is placed within the `dashboardBody()` section. I also use icons in my dashboard which does not prevent the CSS from linking for me.

```
ui <- dashboardPage(

dashboardHeader(title = "Text Analysis"),

dashboardSidebar(

  sidebarMenu(

    menuItem("Home", 
             tabName = "home", 
             icon = icon("home")
             )

),

dashboardBody(
  
  includeCSS("www/style.css"), # Link to style sheet
  
  tabItems(

    tabItem(tabName = "home", 
            homeUI("home")
     ),

  )
 )
)
```

Feel free to ignore this if you have not yet explored modules in Shiny apps yet...
My Shiny app uses modules, hence the homeUI() call in the tab item, and the CSS still renders on child and adjacent modules too. I am yet to explore whether CSS linked on child modules is rendered in parent modules. In the meantime, it is handy that the CSS is passed down for anyone wondering if they need to make an `includeCSS()` call in every module - you don't!

Answer (score 0):

so what if you launch the app in external browser and the open the Developer Tool. Do you have the css file linked to the app successfully? something like below the screenshot:
[image]

weirdly, the first time I ran the app, the css file is empty but I tried one more time, it is ok now

After some more checking, the root casue for this might be:
below this warning is causing some issues for the browser to link the CSS file, so please use `icon = icon("dashboard", verify_fa = FALSE)` in the code to see if it works

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion, but it didn't work. I've tried both adding "verify_fa = FALSE" and removing the whole "icon" part and nothing changes